# Finding the matrix of transformation for $3\times 3$ matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Consider the matrices
$$
            X= 
            \begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 0 & 0 \\
                0 & 1 & 0 \\
                0 & 0 & 1
            \end{bmatrix},
            \qquad Y=
            \begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 0                   & 0 \\
                0 & -\frac{1}{2}        & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
                0 & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}  & -\frac{1}{2}
            \end{bmatrix},
            \qquad Z=
            \begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 0                   & 0 \\
                0 & -\frac{1}{2}        & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
                0 & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} & -\frac{1}{2}
            \end{bmatrix}.$$
Can someone tell me if there is a matrix of transformation $P$ such that
$$
PXP^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix},\quad PYP^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&1\\ 1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\end{bmatrix},\quad PZP^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 1&0&0\end{bmatrix}?
$$
I believe that $P$ exists, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: what are $Y^3$ and $Z^3 \; ? \; \; $

Comment: @WillJagy rotation matrices by $120^\circ$ about $x$-axis. 
$$
R_x(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\0&\sin\theta&\cos\theta \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: @Gonçalo, I tried to find it by writing out explicitly $PYP^{-1}$ with symbols $p_{11}, p_[12}$ etc., but that didn't seem to be a good procedure.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with similarity transformation, you may need to read about it.

Comment: The answer is yes, and this follows from the fact that $Y$ and $Z$ are inverses (as are the desired $PYP^{-1}$ and $PZP^{-1}$

Comment: Pick a vector at random. Then with probability $1$, it is a cyclic vector of $Y$. Repeat until you really obtain a cyclic vector. Then set $P=\pmatrix{v&Yv&Y^2v}^{-1}$ and you are done. The same $P$ also works for $Z$ because $Z=Y^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this problem can be difficult for general $X,Y,Z$, the particular problem is easy because of the following 3 facts:

1. $X$ is the identity matrix, so $PXP^{-1} = X = I$ will be the same for any choice of $P$
2. $Z = Y^{-1}$, so if $PYP^{-1}$ has the desired form, it immediately follows that
   $$
   PZP^{-1} = PY^{-1}P^{-1} = (PYP^{-1})^{-1},
   $$
   which is the desired outcome
3. The matrix $Y$ is in a "canonical form". In particular, it is a ["real Jordan form"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices) (or more specifically, "real block-diagonal" form) matrix.

Fact 3 means that a satisfactory choice of $P$ for $Y$ can be found systematically. Facts 1 and 2 mean that such a $P$ will automatically result in the desired transformations to $X$ and $Z$.

Let $M$ denote the desired form for $PYP^{-1}$, namely
$$
M = \pmatrix{0&0&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&0}.
$$
We can block-diagonalize the matrix as follows: begin by calculating the eigenvalues of $Y$. We obtain the characteristic polynomial
$$
\det(M - \lambda I) = \lambda^3 - 1 = (\lambda - 1)(\lambda - \omega)(\lambda - \overline{\omega}),
$$
where $\omega = e^{2 \pi i/3} = -\frac 12 + i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $\bar \omega$ denotes the complex-conjugate of $\omega$. Conclude that the eigenvalues of $M$ are $1, \omega, \bar \omega$. Next, we calculate the associated eigenvectors of $M$. An eigenvector of $M$ associated with $1$ is given by $v_1 = (1,1,1)$. An eigenvector of $M$ associated with $\omega$ is given by $v_{\omega} = (1, \bar \omega, \omega) = x + iy$, where $x$ and $y$ are real vectors (i.e. $x,y$ are the real an imaginary parts of $v_\omega$ respectively). Let $a,b$ denote the real and imaginary parts of $\omega$, so that $\omega = a + bi$. We have
$$
Av_\omega = \omega v_\omega \implies\\
A(x + iy) = (a + bi)(x + iy) \implies\\
Ax + iAy = (ax - by) + i(bx + ay) \implies\\
\begin{cases}
Ay = ay + bx\\
Ax = -by + ax.
\end{cases}
$$
Now, consider the basis $\mathcal B = (v_1,y,x)$. Let $P = [v_1\ \ y\ \ x]$. We note that
$$
Av_1 = v_1, \qquad 
Ay = ay + bx,\qquad 
Ax = -by + ax.
$$
It follows that the matrix of $M$ relative to the basis $\mathcal B$ (whose columns correspond to the above equations) is given by
$$
[M]_{\mathcal B} = P^{-1}MP = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&a&-b\\0&b&a} = Y.
$$
That is, we have $P^{-1}MP = Y$. It follows that $M = PYP^{-1}$, as desired.

Thus, the answer to our questions is yes, with one suitable option being
$$
P = [v_1\ \ y\ \ x] = \pmatrix{
1&0&1\\
1&-\sqrt{3}/2&-1/2\\
1&\sqrt{3}/2&-1/2}  \implies\\
P^{-1} = \frac 13\pmatrix{1&1&1\\0&-\sqrt{3}&\sqrt{3}\\2&-1&-1}.
$$
Note that the columns of $P$ are mutually orthogonal. Thus, if we want an **orthogonal** matrix for our solution $P$, it suffices to normalize the columns of $P$ to obtain
$$
P = \pmatrix{
1/\sqrt{3} & 0 & 2/\sqrt{6}\\
1/\sqrt{3} & -1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{6}\\
1/\sqrt{3} & 1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{6}}^{-1} = \pmatrix{
1/\sqrt{3} & 0 & 2/\sqrt{6}\\
1/\sqrt{3} & -1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{6}\\
1/\sqrt{3} & 1/\sqrt{2} & -1/\sqrt{6}}  \implies\\
P^{-1} = P^T = \pmatrix{1/\sqrt{3} & 1/\sqrt{3} & 1/\sqrt{3}\\
0 & -1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2}\\
2/\sqrt{6} & -1/\sqrt{6} & -1/\sqrt{6}}.
$$

Comment: Are you sure about $P$? If I compute $PYP^{-1}$, I'm not getting $M$.

Comment: @CroCo It's certainly plausible that I made a mistake somewhere along the way; I'll check more thoroughly when I get the chance. Is there any chance that you used $P^{-1}$ instead of $P$?

Comment: @CroCo, when I calculate $PYP^{-1}$ I get $Y$, actually as I wanted.

Comment: I'm sure. this is my Matlab script
`a = 120;
Y = [1      0         0;
     0 cosd(a) -sind(a);
     0 sind(a) cosd(a)];
M=[0 0 1;1 0 0;0 1 0]
P=(1/3)*[1 1 1;0 -sqrt(3) sqrt(3);2 -1 -1];
P*Y*inv(P)`

Comment: @CroCo, your $P$ isn't quite like written in the answer.

Comment: @Logi what is the difference?

Comment: @CroCo, sorry I was looking at the wrong $P$. When I do the calculation with your matrices I get the desired result, but you have to change the definition of $P$, $P\rightarrow P^{-1}$.
That is, $P^{-1}YP=Y$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann, Thanks a lot for the very thorough answer!

Comment: @CroCo After finally rereading it, I can see that I reversed the role of $P$ and $P^{-1}$, as Logi stated. I think that everything is correct now.